# Property mapping for yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I use yii2 basic template and I need a property mapping.

```
@property boolean passwordExpired
class User implements IdentityInterface {

}
```

I have a property passwordExpired, in my code I want to use this variable so

```
$user->passwordExpired = true;
```

but in my database I want the property save it with lowercase like this:

password_expired

Now I need a mapping for this...

In Grails I can realize this so:

```
static mapping = {
    passwordExpired(column: 'password_expired')
}
```

I want the same for yii2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Prepare getter and setter for it. DB implementation is up to you but let's say you want to store it as 0|1.

```
public function getPasswordExpired()
{
    return (bool)$this->password_expired;
}

public function setPasswordExpired($value)
{
    $this->password_expired = (int)$value;
}
```

Now just use it like:

```
$this->passwordExpired = true; // sets $this->password_expired = 1
```